# Transformation of color in the UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a UIImage on a white background [src image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y018vbkhimbx45d/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%2002.02.14,%2019%2004%2049.png)
I need to remove the white background and display it on another figure in the background white color gradation [dst image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0r1fkbyc93q14k/2.png)
How this could be done in the best way?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, Core Graphics provides mask by color function. Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHCADE

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to generate the source image with a proper alpha channel. But I'll assume you're unable to do that for some reason.

You could do the equivalent of a [`luma key`](http://www.tfwm.com/0709thebasics) on it. There's no built-in luma key filter in iOS, so you'd have to make your own, either from Core Image filters or by manually manipulating the src image (or a copy of it).

If you want to go the [`Core Image`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorInvert) route, you could color invert the src and destination, do an additive blend of the two, then color invert the result.

Alternatively, you could get the pixels of the src image and generate an alpha channel using some math. For example the inverse of the luminance (the luminance coefficients are described [`here`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709#Luma_coefficients)).

Note that your src image you posted is going to be difficult to see over the dest image you posted since they're both mostly cyan colored.